# Bloomberg/Excel: Calculating expected total return of bond at maturity

Tags: excel, finance, bloomberg

I am using an excel spreadsheet with the Bloomberg add-in to look a series of bonds. I am wondering if there is a clean way to calculate the expected total return (nominal future value, no discounting) of a bond assuming full payout at maturity. For example, in the case of a zero coupon bond, the total return would be: Par Value minus Dirty Price Paid. But for a non-callable bullet bond, I do not know of a simple "one cell, one formula" way to account for the coupon payments.

I tried to find a Bloomberg field that produces this but their total return field only calculates backward looking, not expected total return.

Comment: have you looked at the various "yield" fields?

Comment: Further to my answer on cashflows, one far simpler way is the get the dirty price of the bond, setting the yield to 0. eg `=BDP("GB00BFX0ZL78 Govt","PX_DIRTY_BID","YLD_YTM_BID",0)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the OP is after the expected cashflows of a bond, rather like the `CSHF` function returns on the Bloomberg Terminal. This table is available via the DAPI as a "Bulk Data" field `DES_CASH_FLOW` via the `BDS()` Excel function.

eg for a given ISIN code:

[image]

This brings back the flows for a 1mm notional position, based on today's settlement date. If you want a different start date you use the SETTLE_DT override.

To sum up the coupon & principal flows in one cell (assuming you are on an up-to-date Excel version), you can use this formula (assuming the ISIN is in cell B4)

```
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(BDS(B4 & " Corp","DES_CASH_FLOW","ARRAY=TRUE"),2,3))
```

[image]

Bloomberg uses the "old-school" (CSE) array formula for `BDS` by default. By adding the `ARRAY=TRUE` option, you can instead get the more useful dynamic array version. What the formula is doing is simply adding up columns 2 & 3 of the cash flow table.

For a fully-featured function, if your Excel has the `LAMBDA` function then you can take it a stage further and create you own re-usable function. Put this formula into a Name, using the Name Manager:

```
=LAMBDA(isin,settle,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(BDS(isin&" Corp","DES_CASH_FLOW","ARRAY=TRUE","SETTLE_DT",settle),2,3)))
```

[image]

which you can then use wherever you like:
[image]

NB. The settle date you chose has to be on or after the first settlement date of the bond (`FIRST_SETTLE_DT`).